# Router.use() throwing error when i add routes via foreach in app.js

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack

I am stuck at a problem which was not a problem in my prior project when i did witht the same method. I am trying to add the routes and the file path in following way:

And in the App.js file i am including it this way

```
app.use(app.router);

APIRoutes.forEach(function (object) {
    app.use(object.route, require(object.path));
});
```

Now once i do this it shows error

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node ./bin/www`
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node ./bin/www`
c:\Node\mytestapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:458
  throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a 
' + gettype(fn))
  ^

TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object
at Function.use 
(c:\Node\mytestapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:458:13)
at Function.<anonymous> 
(c:\Node\mytestapp\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:220:21)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Function.use 
(c:\Node\mytestapp\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:217:7)
at c:\Node\mytestapp\app.js:34:8
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Node\mytestapp\app.js:33:11)
```

I did the same in my prior projects & their it was working fine. The more insights to the problem i got was that my previous project was in express 2.0.0 framework & now some components are depricated now. but i did not get any solution to this.

**Update**
product.js file

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ProductModel = new Schema({
productId: Number,
name: String,
quantity: Number,
price: Number,
activeStatus: Number
});

const Product = mongoose.model('myProduct', ProductModel);
module.exports = Product;
```

Comment: One of the modules that you require using `require(object.path)` is returning an object instead of a function. Add `console.log(object)` before `app.use(...)` to find out which.

Comment: After running console.log(object) i got this `{ route: '/product', path: './model/product.js' }` which is fine. Why the error then?

Comment: So what does `./model/product.js` export?

Comment: I have updated the question. Please see the file below

Comment: You can't use a Mongoose model as a request handler, those are two very different things.

Comment: Oh shit..Now i got it. I forgot checking it under pressure..Thanks @robertklep